# Adding an attribute to a list

Tags: python

In python how do you add an attribute to a list to perform an operation?

Suppose you have a class like:

```
class TestClass:

    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst

    def test(self, lst):
        """

        >>> t1 = TestClass([1,2,3,4])
        >>> t1.test(self.lst).size
        4

        """
```

if you attach the attribute size to the function test it will return the length of self.lst. So, `return len(self.lst)`

Comment: That wouldn't make sense - and why would you want to do that over `return len(self.lst)` - and what's that other `lst` in `test`? What exactly are you trying to do - I suspect it isn't making function attributes...

Comment: just as an example. Wasn't going to use that for what i'm doing. But just for this example.

Comment: Would you care to explain what it is **you are doing** then? - I strongly suspect this is an XY problem, and any answers to what you *might* be asking may not be suitable for what you're *actually* trying to achieve here...

Comment: To be more correct, you're talking about methods here rather than functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that:

```
t1.test(self.lst).size
```

Is equivalent to:

```
a = t1.test(self.lst)
a.size
```

You're not accessing an attribute on the method, but on the *return value* of the method. You may want something like this:

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst

    def test(self):
        # do something to self.lst (rather than passing it in again)

    @property
    def size(self):
        return len(self.lst)

>>> t = TestClass([1,2,3,4])
>>> t.test()
...
>>> t.size
4
```

If you *really* want to add this to the list, then you'll need to wrap it in something that provides the `size` method:

```
class SizeList(list):
    @property
    def size(self):
        return len(self)

class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = SizeList(lst)

    def test(self):
        # do something here
        return self.lst

>>> t = TestClass([1,2,3,4])
>>> t.test().size
4
```